# Is MAP_HUGETLB synonym of coherent memory? (when successful)

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, huge-pages

Am I correct to assume the mmap'd memory using `MAP_HUGETLB|MAP_ANONYMOUS` is actually 100% physically coherent? at least on the huge page size, 2MB or 1GB.

Otherwise I don't know how it could work/be performant since the TLB would need more entries...

Comment: By "coherent" you mean contiguous in physical memory?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Contiguous in physical memory for eventually DMA ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. Indeed, as you point out, in case they weren't, multiple page table entries would be needed for a single huge page, which would defeat the entire purpose of having a huge page.

Here's an excerpt from [`Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/C/source/Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst):

> The default for the allowed nodes--when the task has default memory
> policy--is all on-line nodes with memory.  **Allowed nodes with
> insufficient available, contiguous memory for a huge page will be
> silently skipped** when allocating persistent huge pages.  See the
> discussion below `<mem_policy_and_hp_alloc>` of the interaction
> of task memory policy, cpusets and per node attributes with the
> allocation and freeing of persistent huge pages.
>
> **The success or failure of huge page allocation depends on the amount of physically contiguous memory that is present in system** at the time
> of the allocation attempt.  If the kernel is unable to allocate huge
> pages from some nodes in a NUMA system, it will attempt to make up the
> difference by allocating extra pages on other nodes **with sufficient
> available contiguous memory**, if any.

See also: [How do I allocate a DMA buffer backed by 1GB HugePages in a linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19460544/3889449)